# from bottom second line check the syntax, I am getting error in eclipse ide

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
import java.util.*;

class sample {

    int rollno;
    String name;
    int age;

    sample(int rollno, String name, int age) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sample s1 = new sample(1, "praveen", 22);
        sample s2 = new sample(2, "rajesh", 23);
        sample s3 = new sample(3, "ganesh", 24);
        sample s4 = new sample(4, "jyothi", 25);
        sample s5 = new sample(5, "sathish", 26);

        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al.add(s1);
        al.add(s2);
        al.add(s3);
        al.add(s4);
        al.add(s5);

        Iterator itr = al.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            sample sa = itr.next();
            System.out.println(sa.rollno + " " + sa.name + " " + sa.age);
        }

    }
}
```

Please find the error in the bottom second line and explain me why its happening?

Comment: please follow class naming convention by reading http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Fix the indention. Format your code!

Comment: Come on ! the class is not even readable !

Comment: "please find the error in the bottom second line" - why don't _you_ tell us what error you get and mark the line in question? To me the "bottom second line" would be `   }`. ;)

Comment: Use code editor like eclipse it will automatically tell you `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to sample` and also provide option of fixing it `Add cast`

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast your object with `(sample)` like this :

```
sample sa = (sample) itr.next();
```

Or you can specify the type of your Iterator like this :

```
Iterator<sample> itr = al.iterator();
```

Comment: Its fine. But why should we do like that?

Comment: @PraveenGandepalli if you'd use generics you shouldn't have to do that. If you don't know why either generics or the cast are necessary you should revisit your Java basics.

Comment: As u said, i used generics and removed (sample)..again its shows error

Comment: @PraveenGandepalli because you don't specify the type of your Iterator, you can solve your problem also with the second solution, check my edit

Comment: ya its working now.. give me some explanation about it

Comment: i told you, java not detect the type automatically, you should to specify the type of your Iterator, of you should to cast your object to the right type get it @PraveenGandepalli

Answer (score 1):

just use `ArrayList<sample> al = new ArrayList<sample>();`

for clarity

Also you should follow Java naming convention. The first letter of a class is begins with the capital letter so it will be `Sample`

Comment: And probably use `List<sample> al = ...` as well :)

Comment: @PraveenGandepalli do you exprience any more problem?

Comment: @Thomas i don't think this solve the problem, you should to specify the type in your Iterator and not in ArrayList `Iterator<sample> itr = al.iterator();` i'm wrong?

Comment: @YCF_L if you define `List<sample> al` (or `ArrayList<sample>`) then `al.iterator()` will return a `Iterator<sample>`. If you use generics you should use it consistently. Just defining `List al` doesn't do any good since the compiler can't know what's allowed to go into `al` so it wouldn't allow `Iterator<sample> itr = al.iterator();` - at least it would issue a warning.

Comment: check this https://ideone.com/xctmne and check this https://ideone.com/o9K2jp how did you explain this @Thomas

Comment: @YCF_L try `al.add("some evil string");` and see what you get in your second version. Then try the same in the first version (after you fixed the compilation problem).

Comment: mmm, yes @Thomas you are correct in the first part you should to specify the type of your list `List<sample>` AND you should also specify the type in your Iterator or you should to cast your object right?

Comment: @Thomas i think both of us solve a part of the error thank you for the information i appreciate it ;)